# VBScript return value in string

Tags: vbscript

I am working with a product that uses VBScript extensively and I need to parse a string to extract specific data.  I know how to do this with other languages, but need to be pointed in the right direction with VBScript please.

Here's the string I am reading from a text file.

```
<PGConfiguration GPOName="Production Policy" GPODisplayName="Production Policy" GPOVersion="0" />
```

The value between GPOName="I_NEED_THIS_DATA" needs to be pulled. It is not expected to be the same between instances.

I have a script that uses InStr() to make sure GPOName= exists and gives me the character position.  I've been able to use that with Mid() to start after the GPOName=".  I don't know how to find the count or position to the closing quote.

Am I going down the right path with InStr() and Mid(), or is there a better way to approach this (regex maybe??)

This code will open the file, read in the contents and pop up a box with the first 10 characters of what I am trying to get to.  Where do I go from here?

Thanks!

```
Dim objFSO, objTextFile, Stream, strSearchFor, strFileName, strLine, strPosition
' the file to check
strFileName = "C:\checkme.txt"
' what are we looking for
strSearchFor = "GPOName="

' create the object and open the file
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Stream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, 1, False)
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, 1, 0)

' read the first line with my data on it
strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()
' do an InStr to get the position of the data
strPosition = InStr(strLine, strSearchFor)
' set the offset to 9 to get to the end of the ="
strPosition = strPosition + 9
' print of the first 10 characters after the GPOName=" match
wscript.Echo Mid(strLine,strPosition,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on if you need to achieve this using string or XML, you can use either of them

```
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, 1, 0)

' read the first line with your data on it
strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()

arr = split(strLine , "GPOName",2)

arr2 = Split(arr(1),"""")
msgbox arr2(1)
```

Need to try if you can load your file as an XML or just load the line as XML as seen below. This is a cleaner solution.

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDOCUMENT")
objXML.loadXML strLine 
msgbox objXML.selectSingleNode("PGConfiguration/@GPOName").text 'Or nodevalue, whichever suites you
Set objXML = Nothing
```

Comment: Good call on the XML, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided by Mithilesh, If you want to use Regex, you can try the following:

```
Dim objFSO, objTextFile, strFileName, strTemp, objReg, objMatches
' the file to check
strFileName = "C:\checkme.txt"

' create the object and open the file
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, 1, False)

'Read all the data, store in a variable and close the file
strTemp = objTextFile.ReadAll()
objTextFile.Close

'Regex code
Set objReg = New RegExp
objReg.Global=True
objReg.Pattern = "(?:GPOName="")([^""]+)(?="")"     'In vbscript, if we want to have a double quote inside a string, it has to be preceded with another double quote to escape it. If just one double-quote is used, it may indicate end or start of a new string.
If objReg.Test(str) Then
    Set objMatches = objReg.Execute(str)
    objMatches.Item(0).Submatches.Item(0)           'Returns the 1st match; To get all the matches run the loop to objMatches.Count
End If
Set objReg = Nothing
Set objFso = Nothing
```

[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/HKwCIA/2)

> Regex explanation: (?:GPOName=")([^"]+?)(?=")
>
> ( - Starts a Group
>
> ?: - makes the current group a non-capturing group
>
> GPOName=" - Finds the substring - GPOName"
>
> ) - Non-Capturing group ends
>
> ( - Starts a group which we want to capture. Notice that it is not
>   followed by ?:
>
> [^"] - matches a character which is NOT a double quote
>
> + - repeats the preceding token 1 or more times greedily(as many times as possible i.e, as long as there is a match)
>
> ) - Capturing Group Ends
>
> (?=") - Positive Lookahead. It means that a double quote must follow
>   the preceding string matched/returned by our capturing group. The
>   double quote will not be the part of the match

For learning the Regular expression basics, refer [THIS](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: I am a starter in regex patterns. Would be great if you could explain the pattern that is used in your answer..... "(?:GPOName="")([^""]+)(?="")"

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar You can see the explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/HKwCIA/1
Also, If you want to practice regex, this is the best site available :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kira

Comment: @Kira , thank you for the answer and the detailed explanation!  This is very valuable info.  I went with Mithilesh's answer as I think it made the most sense in this scenario. Thank you!